# How do I save a JavaScript object that can immidiately be exported?

Tags: javascript, object, save

I want to save a Javascript object in its own file. I do this using util

```
var util = require("util");
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```

In the console, I use the command

```
node createMyObject.js > myObject.js
```

When it saves in a file it looks like this

```
myObject {
    head:"foo"
}
```

I want it to save like this:

```
module.exports = {
    head:"foo"
}
```

Right now I do this process by hand.

Is there a way I can expedite this process so I can just run the code in the createMyObject file and then immediately be ready to access it from a different file without having to manually change the name of the object?

Comment: prepend your util-using script with: `console.log("module.exports=")`, which sets up the console output to spit out your desired result.

Comment: This does not work. Anything that has the first 'myObject' fails.